# python: how to change the value of function's input parameter?

Tags: python, function, parameters, reference, mutable

I tried to modify the value of a string inside a function, like below:

```
>>> def appendFlag(target, value):
...     target += value
...     target += " "
...
>>> appendFlag
<function appendFlag at 0x102933398>
>>> appendFlag(m,"ok")
>>> m
''
```

Well, seems the "target" is only changed within the function, but how to make the new value viable outside the function? Thanks.

Comment: `return` it. Perhaps?

Comment: @DirtyBit, that obviously won't work for the `__init__` method.

Comment: If you need to maintain a program: this is the BEST missing possibility of Python. How often (in other languages and "source == documentation") did a changing parameter value not cause hours of debugging to find an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is handled in python by returning.

```
def appendFlag(target, value):
   target += value
   target += " "
   return target
```

you can use it like this:

```
m = appendFlag(m,"ok")
```

you can even return several variables like this:

```
def f(a,b):
   a += 1
   b += 1
   return a,b
```

and use it like this:

```
a,b = f(4,5)
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use an object that can be modified

```
>>> m = []
>>> def appendFlag(target, value):
...     target.append(value)
...     target.append(" ")
...
>>> appendFlag(m, "ok")
>>> m
['ok', ' ']
```

Answer (score 3):

Mutable data types, such as lists or dictionaries, can be changed from within the function without returning:

```
def duplicate_last(l):
    l.append(l[-1])

l = [1, 2, 3]
duplicate_last(l)
```

The reason for that is different memory management for mutable and immutable objects in python.

Answer (score 1):

The variables inside the function has got only function scope, if you change the value of the variable from inside the function it wont get reflected outside the function. If you want to change the value of the global variable m, update it from outside the function as follows

```
 def appendFlag(target, value):
        target += value
        target += " "
        return target
  m=''
  m=appendFlag(m,'ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function needs to return the new value.
The `target` variable only has scope within the `appendFlag` function.

```
def appendFlag(target, value):
   ...
   return target

m = appendFlag(m, "ok")
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a new class and set the target as the member of class. Then try setattr(class, 'target', value).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: works only within the class, not in global scope